Converting Shell_NotifyIcon Balloon Tips to TNotificationCenter
I am upgrading my widget and planning if I should convert NotifyIcon Balloon Tips to TNotificationCenter notifications.  How the following code can be replaced with TNotificationCenter? Is there support in Delphi 2007 for TNotificationCenter?
And what would be the benefit to do this conversion, is it possible to e.g. configure tip to remain a bit longer on screen with TNotificationCenter API?  NotifyIcon API TimeOut does not seem to work anymore.
procedure TForm1.Button4Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  if ( boIconAdded ) then begin
    StrPLCopy(nidIconData.szInfo, Memo1.Text, 255);
    StrPLCopy(nidIconData.szInfoTitle, Edit2.Text, 63);
    nidIconData.uFlags := NIF_INFO;
    if ( Shell_NotifyIcon(NIM_MODIFY, @nidIconData) ) then
      Memo2.Lines.Add('Balloon tip sent.')
    else
      Memo2.Lines.Add('Failed to send balloon tip.');
  end;
end;


"Is there support in Delphi 2007 for TNotificationCenter?" - No. TNotificationCenter was added in 10.0 Seattle. For older versions, you would have to access the relevant platform API manually. Which on Windows is the WinRT ToastNotificationManager and ToastNotifier APIs. See http://blog.blong.com/2020/09/delphi-and-winrt-api.html "NotifyIcon API TimeOut does not seem to work anymore" - if you are referring to the NOTIFYICONDATA.uTimeout field, it was deprecated in Vista.
